# In c# i am always getting Autoincrementseed value as 0 in table definition even though that table's column's value set seed as 1 in ms sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I am creating tables by c# code from sql server. For that i have created one dynamic table creation function in which i have passed some parameters.One of the parameter is datatable in which i am getting column detail.Everything is working fine but the one minor issue is if there is table in sql with identity(1,1)

[image: sql table screenshot]

i am getting that column's seed value as 0 in c# and hence the data is inserting with id value 0.

[image: code debugging screenshot]

For getting table's defintion from database, i am using simple query like

```
select * from tablename
```

Tell me if any further details or any extra code needed then i can provide it here.

Ok i have updated my question with how i am filling my datatable.

```
sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from item.TableName", connSource);
dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(sqlcmd.ExecuteReader());
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole code of your ado.net ?

Comment: Why you expect that it is 1? How is the DataTable filled, maybe there is the issue

Comment: @TimSchmelter because i have set identity as (1,1) in database while creating that table and i am expecting same definition of that table with seed value 1 instead of 0. And for filling datatable like i have mentioned i am simply using select * from query.

Comment: @kandarp: You should show that code, for example: `using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tablename", con))
                {
                    var t = new DataTable();
                    da.FillSchema(t, SchemaType.Source);
                }`

Comment: Are you sure this is an actual issue? I seem to recall that there are some circumstances where an empty table will report different identity information in some metadata queries than a table that has been inserted into. Can't find that document at the moment, but is this an actual problem when rows are inserted?

Comment: (Also, insert my standard rant about, if you care about the actual numerical values of an identity column, you're probably using it wrong. Treat them as opaque blobs that *happen* to fit in numeric columns and you'll be alright)

Comment: what if you insert new records into the table ? Does the Id column increase from 0 and 1, 2, 3.....? what about primary key setting?

Comment: @kandarp: you don't need to load a complete database table into memory if you just want to retrieve schema informations. Use `DataAdapter.FilLSchema` or `DataReader.GetSchemaTable` or `Connection.GetSchema`

Comment: @KayLee yes exactly what it happens. New records inserted with id 0 instead of 1. which is wrong

Comment: Can you show all the code for sql table creation so that someone can reproduce this issue?

Comment: I mean the code to create sql table including the yellow color code you show.

Comment: @KayLee thanks for the help. I have resolved my problem from the answer i have got.

Comment: Congratulations ! Hope your good days :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below query in C# code and pass tablename to get Seed and Step:

```
 SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT IDENT_SEED(TABLE_NAME) AS    
 Seed,IDENT_INCR(TABLE_NAME) AS Increment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1 AND 
 TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = '" + tableName + "'", 
 srcConStr);

 SqlDataReader readercmd = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

 while (readercmd.Read())
 {
    sqlsc += " IDENTITY(" + readercmd["Seed"].ToString() + "," +    
    readercmd["Increment"].ToString() + ") ";
 }

 readercmd.Close();
```